# Read a char on gotoxy() point from Console?

Tags: c, console, getch

I want to read a char from Console on the specific point of Console. I have to do it with gotoxy() and after that I need a function that can get a char on this point.

I tried it that way :

code ......

```
void charTest(int x , int y){
char test ;
gotoxy(x,y);
test = getch();

if(test == '_'){
}else{
  
    // other code...

}
}
```

The problem is I want to do it automatically and without pressing enter. It has to look on point (x , y ) and if the char == '_' it has to break.
Thank You :)

Comment: I'm afraid that there is no generic way to read characters from the screen the console runs  on. The exception proves the rule. You might like to look into the "ncurses" library.

Comment: What compiler and operating system are you using? It is some old Borland compiler? Most modern compilers do not have a function called `gotoxy`, as it is not part of the ISO C standard

Comment: I can haz an os tag? I recall a gotoxy but it's for DOS and if it is for DOS I can't answer. :(